# How do I remove a parent when a child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

How can I remove the entire div when any child image is clicked?  Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="list1">
        <img src="FILE1.JPG" class="img">
        <img src="FILE2.JPG" class="img">
        <img src="FILE3.JPG" class="img">
</div>

<div id="list2">
        <img src="FILE4.JPG" class="img">
        <img src="FILE5.JPG" class="img">
        <img src="FILE6.JPG" class="img">
        <img src="FILE7.JPG" class="img">
</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save-image.php?q=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $img.closest('div').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

I need to run an update script upon an image click, but then I need the entire div to disappear.  This code is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751521/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913761/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942294/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596468/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010260/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887648/

Comment: Why have you updated your code based on the answers?

Comment: The answer putting the remove statement above the success and saving the att id to a variable.

   $('img').click(function() {
    var ids = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?q=' + ids,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/MJySw/)**

```
$('img').click(function(){    
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

It would be better if you could assign some class to img

```
$('.img').click(function(){    
  $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked - at least I got to see it work after I got into the demo.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: So who downvoted all the answers? Is there anything wrong with them?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('img').click(function() {

    var clicked = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?q=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

            clicked.parent('div:first').remove();

        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: @user1614427 This code should work, although :first is not needed, surely you have other problems.

Comment: Shoot, that did not fix it either.

Comment: If the success callback is not called it will never work. Add the error callback to see that it works:

error: function(data) {clicked.parent('div:first').remove();}

http://jsbin.com/avuwab/7/

Answer (score 2):

You can try parent and remove methods

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?q=' + $this.attr('id'),
        dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
            $this.parent().remove();
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: This one seems super straight forward, but it does not remove the div as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you can:

```
$('img').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) should help you in accomplishing your task.

> parent( [selector] ) Returns: jQuery Description: Get the parent of
>   each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally
>   filtered by a selector.

The first example given on the page is nearly identical to your problem.